# How can I search through an Elasticsearch index by filtering with multiple parameters in Python and not pull up the validated request but json body

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-dsl

I have some technical questions about my deployment and wondering my I'm unable to create a search engine as the backend deployment keeps failing. Additionally, I've already ingest data into my index, search-movies, and am attempting to search through the data by getting the requests using Python.
In my only document, I have two parameters that I want to be able to search by, genres and airlines. I have made both of these parameters as lists of values, in which I wish to be able to develop the search ui with click-on filters for the search engine, enabling users to add as many different airlines and genres that they would like to search by.
Currently, I'm stuck on the ability to be able to search by such filters as I'm using

```
resp = client.search(query={"bool": {"filter": {"term": {"Airline": ["AA"]}}}},).
```

Could I get more ideas as to how to accomplish this task?

I want to be able to search for parameters that have values as lists, which I tried above and doesn't work. I'm doing this in Python and I want to see the list of all the movies with these values and not the valid request, which is shown as `{'took': 1, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 14, 'successful': 14, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': {'value': 0, 'relation': 'eq'}, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}}`
whereas I want the list of all movies which come from this request:

```
client.search(query={"terms": {"Airline": ["AA"]}, "terms": {"Genre": ["Drama"]}},).
```

Could I get tips on this issue?